# ImapX utility not showing Attachments in Message

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have one email with one file attachment and body contains signature. When I am reading email by ImapX I can't getting file attachment.

When Email contains Attachments and EmbeddedResources (like signature in body part) in this case email message only showing EmbeddedResources but not showing Attachments.

I am using "ImapX 2.0.0.18 Binaries\v3.5\ImapX.dll" in Visual Studio 2010.

Is there any Solution for above issue?

Comment: and so far, you've tried...?

Comment: Yes tried..but not succeed.

Answer (score 1):

one alternative is going back to ImapX 2.0.0.16, many are complaining about attachments not showing up in the latest version.

I had this problem too but returning to the previous version, fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to drop in so late, but as Josho Martínez stated, the only way in order to show the attachments is to go back to the 2.0.0.16 version, I am doing the tests with Gmail and Powershell and two emails that had attachments, were not showing in the latest version of ImapX, however, in the 2.0.0.16, that same code (pointing to the old dll) began to show them and to download them.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue and I tried going back to V 2.0.0.16, but this did not correct the missing attachments in ImapX.message

This is what worked for me:

The attachment you are  looking for may be in EmbeddedResources rather than Attachments.
Within an ImapX.message attachments are of type ImapX.Attachment.  EmbeddedResources are also of type ImapX.Attachment.

Iterate through the ImapX.Attachment(s) in EmbeddedResources and look for your attachment.  You can look at the ContentType.MediaType of each ImapX.Attachment to see the media type.

In my case I was looking for:
"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
and
"text/csv"

Once found the attachments within EmbeddedResources can be downloaded and saved just like the ImapX.message.attachments

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I was scanning an IMAPX meeting invitation that had been forwarded to my dropbox (rather than being submitted directly). Because the email invite had been forwarded, the attached .ics file did not show in the 'Attachments' property... but was found in the EmbeddedResources.Attachment list.